# Admin needs root password

Tags: sudo, root, kali-linux

I recently installed it and since I am the only user the system asks me for root password if I want to install something or read any files. Always saying that I don't have permission to access.

Before the installation I had Kali Linux on a boot stick with persistence, actually just for school. So I'm coming to the point: Why didn't the system asked me for a root password when I had the boot stick? Now I always have to type sudo for everything and that's annoying.

Comment: What a tragedy.... Oh wait, its a security Precaution.

Why not let you ruin any chance of security :D

Type "sudo su -"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in this to access your `daemon.conf`-file :

```
root@kali:~# leafpad /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf
```

After pressing enter your file will open in the `leafpad`-editor showing this:

```
[daemon]
# Enabling automatic login
# AutomaticLoginEnable = true
# AutomaticLogin = root
```

For autologin into `root` you have to un-commend the last two lines:

```
[daemon]
# Enabling automatic login
  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
  AutomaticLogin = root
```

Reboot your PC, now you should be logged in as `root`.

Answer (score 1):

You were probably auto logged in as root on the usb stick. Currently you are probably not logging in as root. If that baffles you you can read up on linux user permissions e.g. [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-navigating-ownership.html). Kali linux advices against using it if one is not familiar with linux.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux distros attempt to save you from doing damage to your system by making you use sudo to perform "root-y" operations, a situation you may or not want to accept.

If you can sudo, you can change the root password:

```
# sudo passwd root
```

should do the trick. I'll skip the tedious lecture about being careful what you do as root, you can always reload the system if you mess it up!

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this before and it doesn't change the fact that I still have to write sudo and press enter(because no password).